# Scrolling with svg fixed in background bug on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, svg, scroll, parallax

In my HTML page I have an SVG with animation using Snapsvg in background. I'm using parallax effect and I'm getting scroll position with `window.pageYOffset`. Some content take time to load like some background color

On my laptop everything is OK this is a screenshot:

[image]

The problem is that when I scroll on Android phone or iPhone I get this:

[image]

I found in some forums that using a listening event while scrolling can cause this problem.

This is my CSS:

```
.banner {
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
}

svg {
 width: 100%;
 height: 854px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
}

#svg{
 position: fixed;
 z-index: -1;
 height: 1000px;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<section class="banner">
   <svg id="svg"></svg>
   <svg id="animation"></svg>
</section>
```

Comment: Report it to whatever bugtracker is appropriate for Android.

Comment: site url please ?

Comment: I removed the SVG part.